# Java Array Method .Class error

Tags: java, arrays, methods

im attempting to pass a 2 dimensional array of characters to a method. but keep ending up with a .class expected when compiled. there is a lot of extra code i excluded cause no error

2 errors found:
File: /home/cmehmen/CSC 202/NewFolder/TicTacToe.java  [line: 741]
Error: '.class' expected
File: /home/cmehmen/CSC 202/NewFolder/TicTacToe.java  [line: 741]
Error: ';' expected

```
char [][] matrix2 ={
{' ',' ',' '}, 
{' ',' ',' '},
{' ',' ',' '},


};

//end main

   vicCheck (char[][]matrix2);


 public static void vicCheck(){
 if(matrix2 [0][0] == 'X' && matrix2 [0][1] =='X' && matrix2 [0][2] =='X'){

System.out.println("Player X Wins");
  }   
  if(matrix2 [1][0] == 'X' && matrix2 [1][1] =='X' && matrix2 [1][2] =='X'){

System.out.println("Player X Wins");
   }
   if(matrix2 [2][0] == 'X' && matrix2 [2][1] =='X' && matrix2 [2][2] =='X'){

System.out.println("Player X Wins");
   }
      return;
  }
```

Comment: can't see a acceptable char array parameter in vicCheck() method

Comment: This has quite a few syntax errors. You may want to go read about how to create methods with parameters...

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've posted, you appear to be confused about *actual parameters* and *formal parameters* and the syntax thereof -

```
// vicCheck (char[][]matrix2);
vicCheck (matrix2); // <-- actual parameters
```

and

```
// public static void vicCheck(){
public static void vicCheck(char[][]matrix2){ // <-- formal parameters
```

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha Not necessarily. It only has to be in scope for the call.